# "XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL" on Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

I installed LAMPP with [these](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) instructions, but phpmadmin didn't work so i tried to uninstall and then install it again and it still doesn't work. When I'm trying to turn it on i get these errors.

```
jeggy@jeggy-12:~/Niðurtøkur$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: Another FTP daemon is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
jeggy@jeggy-12:~/Niðurtøkur$
```

I have tried

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl stop
```

And none of them work

When i go to localhost/phpmyadmin/ i get this error:
[image]

---

**EDIT:**
Now i get this error

```
jeggy@jeggy-12:~/Niðurtøkur/nspire$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

[image]

Comment: "XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running." Is there another web server running? If so ... kill it.

Comment: i know that, but i don't know how to kill it. What i think it can be is that it was on while i deleted it and now when i installed it again it says another already is on

Comment: `ps -ef|grep {whatyouwanttofind}`, find the PID, and do a `kill -9 {pid}`. {whatyouwanttofind} is something like mysql or xampp.

Comment: Ughh, please don't use XAMPP on Linux. We have a perfectly fine [LAMPP stack](//help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#To_install_the_default_LAMP_stack_in_Ubuntu_10.04_and_above) in the package repositories: trivial, single-command installation, much better system integration (incl. better file access permission management), and completely automated (security) updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being googling for days i found [this](http://adventux.blogspot.pt/2012/11/xampp-couldnt-start-mysql.html) and it works great!

What i did was

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql -R
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

and now it works

Comment: Making a whole directory structure writeable and executable to *everyone* is a terrible idea.